# AWS Lambda file Error Issue with /tmp/ folder

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to basically write a file in AWS Lambda. 
Here's my analyze.py script that analyzes the file and writes to Lambda.

```
from main import Analyzer
import argparse
import sys

# Takes helper functions from main.py and prints filament usage and print time 
def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Gcode Info Extractor")
    parser.add_argument('path', type=str)
    return parser.parse_args()

def giveInput():
    args = '/tmp/' + 'output.gcode'
    #path = '/tmp/' + args.path
    analyzer = Analyzer(args)
    time = analyzer.get_time()/60
    filUsage = analyzer.get_filament_usage()
    # Lambda issues, so going to try to make  the return of this function simply the two variables I need..
    neededInput = "%.2f, %s" %(filUsage, time)
    return (neededInput)
```

```
{
  "errorMessage": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/output.gcode'",
  "errorType": "FileNotFoundError",
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
      20,
      "pp_handler",
      "data = giveInput()"
    ],
    [
      "stl2gcode/analyze.py",
      14,
      "giveInput",
      "analyzer = Analyzer(args)"
    ],
    [
      "stl2gcode/main.py",
      45,
      "__init__",
      "self.__process()"
    ],
    [
      "stl2gcode/main.py",
      57,
      "__process",
      "with open(self.__file_path, \"r\") as fp:"
    ]
  ]
}
```

The thing is, when I had the output.gcode file already included in my deployment package on Lambda by mistake, it had no issue simply reading that. But my issue is when I am writing that file.

The way I am writing that file is through a library called `mandoline_py`
I do this command:

```
mandoline -o /tmp/output.gcode -n /tmp/input.stl
```

The problem isn't with the library, because when I try using 'input.stl' instead of 'output.gcode' in my giveInput() function, I have no issues with the file being found by Lambda. Any idea what I can do?

Comment: When are you running this command? `mandoline -o /tmp/output.gcode -n /tmp/input.stl`
You are running this inside the Lambda environment somehow?

Comment: No - it's in a shell script that I call within the lambda function.

Comment: Have you verified that `/tmp/output.gcode` actually exists? As opposed to inferring this from the fact that you can read `/tmp/input.stl`?